# Understanding how $.each executes this code

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jQuery and am trying to understand this piece of code

```
success: function( data) {
        $.each(data.names.name, function(i, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>'). { value: i, text: value.cname }));
        });
    }
```

Please explain what is the code doing?

Comment: What the code is doing depend on `name` (is that an array ? It's strangely named, then). And you should get what happens from $.each documentation.

Comment: It would be easier / more useful if you could show an example of what the variable `data` contains.

Comment: it's looping over a data structure populating a select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.each` will loop over each element in an array (or property in an object) and execute the given function for each element. The function can take up to two parameters. The first will be the index of the item. The second will be the item itself.

In this case, the code adds an option to a select list for each name in `data.names.name`.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> Description: A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

That line though doesn't seem right to me

```
$('#myselect').append($('<option>'). { value: i, text: value.cname }));
```